# Source of a Rabbi Salanter story

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

[This article](https://traditiononline.org/israel-salanter-and-therapeutic-values/) gives several stories about Rav Salanter, in section V of the article.

There’s no citation but many of them are drawn from *T’nuat ha-Mussar* by Rav Katz.

However, I can't find a source for the third story in section V:

> During the afternoon service when he saw that his congregants would
> always run over to the window to yell at the passers-by in the street
> to come in to pray, he ascended the pulpit and asked them, "Why is it
> that I always see you inviting people to the afternoon service to
> pray, and why is it that I never see you during the evening-meal time
> shouting out of your windows, 'those who are hungry come in to eat?'"

Can anyone help?

(It is possible that I’m simply failing to find it in Rav Katz’s book.)